# Child is already added is coming

Tags: ios, c++11, cocos2d-x-3.0

```
sprite=Sprite::create("bg.png");
sprite->setPosition(960,640);
this->addChild(sprite,0);

sprite1=Sprite::create("face.png");
sprite1->setPosition(960+x,640);
sprite->addChild(sprite1,1);

sprite2=Sprite::create("eyeLeft.png");
sprite2->setPosition(960+x,640+y);
sprite1->addChild(sprite2,2);

sprite3=Sprite::create("eyeRight.png");
sprite3->setPosition(960,640+y);
sprite1->addChild(sprite3,2);
```

Here I want to create `sprite1` as MenuItem and add it as child into the same layer i.e. sprite1

But I am getting child already added,  how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd assume

```
sprite1->addChild(sprite3,2);
```

should be

```
sprite2->addChild(sprite3,2);
```

Comment: sorry for mistyping, yeah you r correct...but how can i add into menuitemsprite

Comment: That I don't know. You should probably ask a new question for that.